# React Native navigate to different tab with hardware back button

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am trying to change default android hardware back button behavior with react navigation. I have bottom tab navigator with 6 tabs. eg Tab1 to Tab6 . When i open app from notification (depending on some condition) the initial tabs are Tab5 or Tab6, but when i press android hardware back button i got switched to Tab1 (which is my Home tab) but i want to be switched to Tab4.

I managed to change back button behavior to open some modal and on button to navigate to tab 4. My question is , can that be done without some alerts or modal ?

as per documentation i wraped event listener in useFocusEffect and UseCallback

`const jumpToMessage = TabActions.jumpTo('Message');`

```
useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      const backAction = () => {
        navigation.dispatch(jumpToMessage);
      };
      const subscription = BackHandler.addEventListener(
        'hardwareBackPress',
        backAction
      );
      return subscription.remove();
    }, [])
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `none` for [backBehavior](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#backbehavior) in Navigator to remove default handling and then use `BackHandler` for custom behaviour. Below is the simple example which navigates to the previous tab.

```
const tabs = ['Tab 1', 'Tab 2', 'Tab 3', 'Tab 4', 'Tab 5'];

function Tabs() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const state = useNavigationState((state) => state);

  useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      if (state != undefined) {
        navigation.navigate(tabs[state.index > 0 ? state.index - 1 : 0]);
      }
      return true;
    };

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      backAction
    );

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, [navigation, state]);

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator backBehavior="none">
      {tabs.map((tab) => (
        <Tab.Screen name={tab} component={Screen} />
      ))}
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: yes , it works now. thanks a lot. i just couldnt figure it out. Once again , thanks a lot ... you save my day :)